# Getting asynchronous function in external library with callback to work synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am using a library call to connect to my vendor.   The libary call requires a callback in the call.  Without a callback in the function, I can easily make this synchronous.  With the Callback, everything I do is stuck in the callback and never bubbles it way out.

I have literally tried 100 different ways to get this to work.

```
function removeFromDNC(emailAddress, accessToken_in) 
{
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) 
    {
        try{
            const options = 
            {   
                auth: {
                accessToken: accessToken_in
                }
                , soapEndpoint: 'https://webservice.XXX.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx' 
            };

            var co = {
                "CustomerKey": "DNC",
                "Keys":[
                    {"Key":{"Name":"Email Address","Value": emailAddress}}]
            };

            var uo = {
                SaveOptions: [{"SaveOption":{PropertyName:"DataExtensionObject",SaveAction:"Delete"}}]
              };


            const soapClient = new FuelSoap(options); 
           //again, I don't control the structure of the next call.          
            let res = soapClient.delete('DataExtensionObject', co, uo, async function( err, response ) {
                if ( err ) {
                    // I can get here, but my reject, or if I use return, does nothing
                    
                     reject();
                }else{
                    // I can get here, but my reject, or if I use return, does nothing
                    resolve();
                }
            });
            console.log("res value " + res);  // undefined - of course
            
        }catch(err){
            console.log("ALERT:  Bad response back for removeFromDNC for email: " + emailAddress + " error: " + err);
            console.log("removeFromDNC promise fulfilled in catch");
            reject();  
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: You cannot make asynchronous code synchronous. You ***must*** go through its asynchronous API or you get timing/race issues. There is no way around it. What part of this code is yours and can be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods `resolve` and `reject` expect parameters, which are `res` and `err` in your case. 
As far as `removeFromDNC` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance, you should call it using either async/await syntax:

```
const res = await removeFromDNC(...);
```

or chaining then/catch calls:

```
removeFromDNC(...)
  .then((res) => { ... })    // resolve
  .catch((err) => { ... })   // reject
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to avoid usage of callbacks inside `removeFromDNC`, consider **promisifying** of `soapClient.delete` call. Refer to [util.promisify()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) if you working in Node.js or use own implementation.

Here is the example for demonstration:

```js
const promisify = (fun) => (...args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fun(...args, (err, result) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result);
    })
  })
}

const soapClient = {
  delete: (value, cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => cb(null, value), 10);
  }
};

async function removeFromDNC(emailAddress, accessToken_in) {
  const soapDelete = promisify(soapClient.delete.bind(soapClient));
  const res = await soapDelete('Soap Responce');
  //You can use res here
  return res;
}

removeFromDNC().then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Chaining did not work when I tried that earlier.  It has the same issue where the callback causes issues.

Comment: @AndyP Could you please specify what exactly doesn't work or what you expect? I've attached code snippet for demonstration

Comment: Thank you so much!   That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: For anyone looking at this later. I had to add a bind to this statement to get it to work.  Otherwise, no changes were madeconst soapClientPromisfy = util.promisify(soapClient.delete.bind(soapClient));

Comment: @AndyP You're absolutely right, thank you! Edited